# iOS Airprint without displaying popover dialogue box

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, popover, airprint

I am developing an app that needs to be able to print out name labels after a user finishes a registration process. It needs to do this without displaying a popover which is automatically created when using UIPrintInteractionController.

I know other apps have approaches where they print directly after the user touches a print button that is placed in the view controller. Fx the iPrint&Label app by Brother.

How can I create a similar button that allows the application to print automatically without displaying the popover dialogue box?

p.s The application doesn't have to be app store clean, the final application will only be installed on two specific iPads.

p.p.s this is my first entry on stackoverflow, I hope I'm not being to much of a newbie :-)

Comment: I imagine they are rolling their own printer driver and network controller inside the app.

Comment: There is an iOS SDK for the Brother label printers available from their web site.  It doesn't use AirPrint.  As @bbarnhart said it uses a direct network connection to the printer

Comment: Oh that sounds interesting! I'll try to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible on iOS 8 and newer -  use printToPrinter:
Docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010141-CH1-SW34